# Can I used Step7 as PLC simulator?

Tags: automation, plc, opc, scada

I have PLC program written in Step7.
Also i have SCADA with OPC Server.
I want to simulate PLC with programm from Step7 and connect it to OPC Server, because i want SCADA testing. 
Can I used Ste7 as PLC simulator, how can i do that ?

I founded some blog where what tutorial how to config Step7 and simulator, but doesn't work, this was very old tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution to the fine one from tonteria2424

You could try to load the program into a virtual S7-1500 and activate OPC-UA ..

Follow this 7 virtual steps (step7)

Download trial versions of simatic tia portal from 
https://support.industry.siemens.com/

Google "S7-PLCSIM Advanced trial"
and "tia portal trial"

You need "STEP 7 Professional V14"  SP1 + updates
and "SIMATIC S7-PLCSIM Advanced V1.0 SP1"

Then you can load your program into a virtual plc, connected to a virtúal network adapter and use the opc server(in the virtual plc) as a datasource for your scada and test it for 21 days.

PLCSim Advance can do networking, so testing can be close to "real life".
I have tested this setup many times.

if your scada cannot do opc ua... that was covered by the first answer ;)

(I did not know that NetToPlcSim was opc da capable)

//PerD

Comment: NetToPlcSim adds a TCP/IP interface to S7-PLCSIM and by this way any software that communicates via TCP/IP with real PLC, like for example an OPC Server, also can do it theoretically with PLCSIM. 

But NetToPlcSim does not include an OPC server

Answer (score 0):

Please go the support Site of Siemens and narrow down your question. It is far too open.

But I guess that this might be your answer.
PLC SIM (for 300, 400 and 1200 and 1500) does not support externel connections. Only internal to their HMI/Scada on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you want using PLCSIM + a free software called NetToPlcSim simulating S7 300.

I used Simatic step 7 v5.5  I don't know if it still works with newer versions